# How to apply image CSS3 filters in Ionic 2

Tags: html, image, css, filter, ionic2

I'm trying to improve the resolution of some image by CSS3 filter to edit it automatically and you can find a lot of filters in this link https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_filter.asp

Any way, my problem is when I tried to use id or class inside the img tag to apply the filter on one image, then no changes happens.

This is a sample example of my code

```
<img src="{{noteImg.url}}" style="height:135px !important; margin=0px -webkit-filter: contrast(200%); filter: contrast(200%);"  #imageToView (click)="viewImg(imageToView)"/>
```

> instead I want to apply the effect on some images.

Comment: Add a working example, you probably have something wrong in the syntax/names/properties...

Comment: @Dekel you can see my code for img tag ..

Comment: Where is your css that is related specifically to that image?

Comment: @Dekel I used style. I think its same as CSS

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with the content of the `style` attribute:

```
<img src="{{noteImg.url}}" style="height:135px !important; margin: 0; -webkit-filter: contrast(200%); filter: contrast(200%);"  #imageToView (click)="viewImg(imageToView)"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use your Css in your page-name{}.
eg:
it will be applied to only this metion page

```
page-yourPagename {
 img {
   -webkit-filter: contrast(200%); /* Safari */
   filter: contrast(200%);
 }
}
```

Or try to use class name.

```
page-yourPagename {
 .image {
   -webkit-filter: contrast(200%); /* Safari */
   filter: contrast(200%);
 }
}
```

Comment: I edited the question with my code. is there any mistake ?

Comment: @AliH I didn't get `margin=0px` as I per my knowledge it should be `margin:0xp;` with semicolon. else you code look fine to me.